# In a slice category C/A of a category C over a given object A, What is the role of the identity morphism of A in C with respect to C/A

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra

In a slice category $C/A$ of a category $C$ over a given object $A$, what is the role of  the $C$ identity morphism, $A\to A$ ($1_A$), in $C/A$, particularly with respect to composition?

I understand that as an arrow targeting $A$, it is an object of $C/A$.  However, in $C$, $1_A$ is not practically composable, because it is an identity morphism and $(X\to A) \circ 1_A$ is just reduced to $X\to A$.  This doesn't seem like it would necesarily be the case in $C/A$, because in $C/A$, $1_A$ is not the identity morphism (the commutative diagram that represents $1_A\to 1_A$ should play this role).

It seems possible that $1_A\to 1_A$ could be reduced to $1_A$, but I don't know if this is the case and how I would validate it.  If it isn't the case, then it would seem that for every other object, $Z\to A$ in $C/A$, at least two morphisms would exist: #1, $(Z\to A) \to (Z\to A)$, (the identity morphism in $C/A$); and, #2, $(Z\to A)\to (A\to A)$.

I haven't found such an explanation in the books/articles I've read, which leads me to believe I am misunderstanding something fundamental about how slice categories are derived, but without an authoritative reference, I can't be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "practically composable"? The identity morphism is the terminal object.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, exactly that.  It's not practically composable, because you can't compose it with another morphism to get something new.  I get this part - my question is specifically about what happens when $A\to A$ is no longer the identity morphism (because it is in $C/A$ instead of $C$)

Comment: The identity on $(a,Id_a:a\to a)$ is given by $Id_a$.

Comment: @StefanH., can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You're not supposed to be composing it with another morphism. It's an object in the slice category, not a morphism.

Comment: In $C/A$, $1_A$ is an object, not a morphism. So why would it be composed with anything. (It is a final object in the category, in that every elements of the category has a unique morphism to it...)

Comment: The objects in the slice category are pairs $(x,f)$ where $f:x\to a$, and a morphism from $(x,f)$ to $(y,g)$ is induced by a morphism $h:x\to y$ such that $g\circ h=f$.

Comment: Yes, it is. Why is that surprising? Lots of categories have such an object. For example, in $\text{Set}$, every set has a unique morphism to a singleton set, $1=\{x\}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin, so does it follow that for every object $Z$ in a slice category $C/A$ (other than $A\to A$), that there are at least two morphisms, including the identity morphism ($(Z\to Z) \to (Z\to Z)$) and the morphism: $(Z\to Z) \to (Z\to A)$ ?

Comment: Again, you say $Z$ is in the slice category, but then use $Z\to Z$ as a morphism.  $Z\to Z$ is not an element of the slice category. If $Z\to A$ is in $C/A$ then there is always a an identity morphism $(Z\to A)\to(Z\to A)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that would be the special case I mentioned, "other than $A\to A$", right?  I don't think this is necessarily surprising, but I got a little thrown off by a different question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221814/where-do-the-arrows-in-slice-category-come-from ) and I wanted to make sure I was understanding it correctly

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that was a typo, I will delete + repost that comment

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Is there a special name for such an object in the slice category $C/A$ as $A\to A$, or for a generalization thereof?

Comment: Final objects or terminal objects. They are unique up to isomorphism if they exist in a category.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In $C/A$, $1_A$ is a final object in the category - for every object $f:X\to A$ in $C/A$ there is a unique morphism $f\to 1_A$ - that is, $\hom(f,1_A)$ is always a singleton.

You are confusing $1_A$, with $1_{1_A}$. $1_A$ is an object of $C/A$. $1_{1_A}$ is the identity morphism for that object. That morphism is always trivial with composition, as are all identity morphisms.

It might be useful to consider the basic case of $C=\text{Set}$.  $\text{Set}$ has final objects equal to the singleton sets.

Given a set $A=\{1,2\}$, it turns out that $\text{Set}/A$ is pretty much $\text{Set}\times\text{Set}$. The sets corresponding to $f:X\to A\in \text{Set}/A$ are $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(2)$. Now, if $C_1,C_2$ both have final objects, then $C_1\times C_2$ has a final object. So the final object in $\text{Set}^2$ is just two pairs of singleton sets. But it we reverse the operation, we see that corresponds to an element of $f:X\to A$ which is $1-1$ and onto.

For more general sets $A$, there is a sense in which $\text{Set}/A$ is equivalent to something we can write as $\text{Set}^A$. Again, we see that the final objects must be final at every "point" $a\in A$, and thus that the final objects of $\text{Set}^A$ are just lists of singletons indexed by $A$.

This feature of $\text{Set}$ is specific to that category, but I think it is instructive to see it in action. The finality of $1:A\to A$ is true in all $C/A$.

Answer (score 2):

Objects of $C/A$ are pairs $(X \in C,y : X \to A)$

Maps in $C/A$ between $f : (X \in C,y : X \to A) \to (Z \in C,w : Z \to A)$ are maps $f : X \to Z$ which make the triangle commute: $y = wf$

So $(A \in C, 1_a : A \to A)$ is an object in $C/A$, and $1_a : (A \in C, 1_a : A \to A) \to (A \in C, 1_a : A \to A)$ is a map.

---

Some comments stated $(A \in C, 1_a : A \to A)$ is the terminal object, here's the proof:

take an object $(X \in C,y : X \to A)$

and now $y$ can be seen as a map $(X \in C,y : X \to A) \to (A \in C, 1_a : A \to A)$